# Heap size issue on migrating from Solr 5.0.0 to Solr 5.1.0

Tags: solr, jvm

I have a Solr 5.0.0 in production with a custom heap size like this

```
SOLR_JAVA_MEM="-Xms2g -Xmx2g"
```

When I tried to migrate to Solr 5.1.0 with the same configuration and start the server it returned a `OutOfMemoryError`. Looking to the Solr API I saw that the heap size was set to `512m`. My custom heap configuration is not working in Solr 5.1.0 and the server is starting with the default heap size value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug that occurs just in Solr 5.1. There is an issue resolved that fixed this bug in Solr 5.2.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-7454

The problem is that Solr 5.1 doesn't use `SOLR_JAVA_MEM` to set heap size. It uses `SOLR_HEAP` to set the min and max heap sizes with the same value like this:

```
SOLR_HEAP="2g"
```

This way solr will start with `-Xms=2g` and `-Xmx=2g`

In Solr 5.2 this bug was fixed and the two `SOLR_JAVA_MEM` and `SOLR_HEAP` work fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, with the same SOLR version (v.5.0), I changed it in bin\solr.in.sh file.

[image]

There are other files that has "-Xms512m -Xmx512m", just be aware that those won't update the JVM Memory such as:

1. bin\solr
2. bin\solr.in.cmd
3. bin\solr.cmd